# How to bind this in then callback in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, this, vue-component, vuex, arrow-functions

I am using Vuex in my app. I dispatch an action inside the component. I get back the result in `then()`. I need to assign part of that result to some local variables defined in the Vue component. I am only able to do this if I bind the `then()` with `this`. Is there a way to achieve the same without using `bind`.

Here is my original code, I am talking about the line `this.$store.dispatch`:

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import FlightCard from './FlightCard'

export default {
  name: 'AirportLayout',
  components: {FlightCard},
  props: ['id'],
  data () {
    return {
      cardActivator: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // show flight card menu
    showFlightCard: function (e) {
      // debugger
      let flight = this.$store.state.demo.find(a => {
        return a.flightNr === e.target.id
      })
      this.$store.dispatch('getFlightCard', {flightNr: flight.flightNr, scheduledDate: flight.scheduledDate}).then(function (){
        debugger
        // here I want to do something with the response
        this.cardActivator = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
        console.log('Showing flight card for: ', this.cardActivator)
      }.bind(this)) // Using bind, this gets the value of Vue component
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I read the documentation for arrow functions here [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), it says an arrow function does not create its own `this`, the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used. I assumed that would be the Vue component, and I tried it, but then `this` value was `undefined`. So I concluded the execution context must be referring to the `then()`, am I right? If yes, how could I make `this` inside `then()` refer to the Vue component?

Here is my code using arrow functions

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import FlightCard from './FlightCard'

export default {
  name: 'AirportLayout',
  components: {FlightCard},
  props: ['id'],
  data () {
    return {
      cardActivator: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // show flight card menu
    showFlightCard: function (e) {
      // debugger
      let flight = this.$store.state.demo.find(a => {
        return a.flightNr === e.target.id
      })
      this.$store.dispatch('getFlightCard', {flightNr: flight.flightNr, scheduledDate: flight.scheduledDate}).then(r => {
        debugger
        // here I want to do something with the response
        this.cardActivator = document.getElementById(e.target.id)
        console.log('Showing flight card for: ', this.cardActivator)
      }) // here the value for this is undefined
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work. Are you absolutely sure about your conclusion?

Comment: Yes! Although my first impression was the arrow function is going to be using the value of the Vue component for the `this` but now it seems the `then` is becoming the execution context and there is no more access to the Vue component.

Comment: So if you put `let self = this` at the top of your `showFlightCard` method and compare `self === this` inside the `then` callback, that returns `false`? It should be the same object.

Comment: I tried it, and if I keep the `bind(this)` indeed they are the same, without `bind(this)` they are not the same.